# Deny SSL connections on HTTP server in Java

Tags: java, https, server

Good afternoon everyone,

I'm having some issues with my HTTP server. I've made my own HTTP server (A lightweight HTTP server due some circumstances and needings) that I want to implement on a software I have. This HTTP API also is used to allow HTTPS, but my main issue comes actually with HTTP.

One issue I'm facing is retrieving HTTPS connections on the HTTP server. Using HTTPS as the server and HTTP as the connection from the client gets denied, as the Handshake fails and gives an Exception to the server. The problem using the HTTP server with an HTTPS client is that this connections keeps running, but the message is encrypted. As it's encrypted, I can't read the information and get details like the Content-Length, so the server is waiting for an end that will never come as it can't read correctly the data.

I was wondering if there's a way in Java to detect if the client is using encrypted responses to deny this connections instead of trying to read them. The main issue with this sockets is that they aren't detected as SSLSockets, they are normal sockets that can't decrypt the information in the InputStream.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that HTTP and HTTPS are usually served on different port numbers? So 80 is for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS. For non-privileged ports often 8000 and 8443 are used. A client that connects using TLS on a HTTP-only port is faulty, and your HTTP server should easily detect non-HTTP traffic:

If the first word received isn't one of the HTTP verbs supported by your server, such as GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, etc. your server should send a 400 or 408 response (408 is request timeout, your server should only wait a reasonable amout of time for the request header) and then close the connection.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Anyway, even if HTTP is for port 80 and HTTPS is for port 443, anyone can go and put :443 or :80 on the URL and use encryption or not with any port you want. Is bad to ignore this facts as if you are preparing something from scratch like this, not preventing this is a hole for people to make DoS to the server.

Comment: As you say, anyone can send anything to any port on your server. That's one of the hard facts of life on the internet. Your server needs to be robust in the case of DoS attacks, or you need a specialized reverse proxy in front of it that handles a number of attack types by itself and only passes valid requests on to your server. But of course, then the whole thing isn't lightweight anymore.